# Is there a way to ras:Dynamic Color Map ras:Contour together via SLD?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I've bee trying to create a SLD style for a geoserver service. I would like to create a dynamic colormap to describe the scene with the contour of some areas (with a value over a certain value) highlighted.

I'm able to to the two steps separately, but I'm facing problems when I try to combine them

1) dynamic colormap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
   <sld:NamedLayer>
     <sld:Name/>
     <sld:UserStyle>
       <sld:Name/>
       <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
         <sld:Transformation>                       
           <ogc:Function name="ras:DynamicColorMap">
             <ogc:Function name="parameter">
               <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
             </ogc:Function>
             <ogc:Function name="parameter">
               <ogc:Literal>opacity</ogc:Literal>
               <ogc:Function name="env">
                 <ogc:Literal>OPACITY</ogc:Literal>
                 <ogc:Literal>1.0</ogc:Literal>
               </ogc:Function>
             </ogc:Function>
             <ogc:Function name="parameter">
               <ogc:Literal>colorRamp</ogc:Literal>
               <ogc:Function name="colormap"        <ogc:Literal>rgb(241,248,241);rgb(214,234,214);rgb(187,221,187);rgb(161,207,161);rgb(134,194,134);rgb(107,180,107);rgb(80,167,80);rgb(53,153,53);rgb(26,140,26);rgb(0,127,0)</ogc:Literal>
                 <ogc:Function name="env">
                   <ogc:Literal>COLORSCALERANGE_MIN</ogc:Literal>
                   <ogc:Function name="bandStats">
                     <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>minimum</ogc:Literal>
                   </ogc:Function>
                 </ogc:Function>   
                 <ogc:Function name="env">
                   <ogc:Literal>COLORSCALERANGE_MAX</ogc:Literal>
                   <ogc:Function name="bandStats">
                     <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                     <ogc:Literal>maximum</ogc:Literal>
                   </ogc:Function>
                 </ogc:Function>                
                 <ogc:Function name="env">
                   <ogc:Literal>BELOWMINCOLOR</ogc:Literal>
                   <ogc:Literal>rgba(0,0,0,0)</ogc:Literal>
                 </ogc:Function>              
                 <ogc:Function name="env">
                   <ogc:Literal>ABOVEMAXCOLOR</ogc:Literal>
                   <ogc:Literal>rgba(0,0,0,0)</ogc:Literal>
                 </ogc:Function>             
                 <ogc:Function name="env">
                   <ogc:Literal>LOGSCALE</ogc:Literal>
                   <ogc:Literal>false</ogc:Literal>
                 </ogc:Function>             
                 <ogc:Function name="env">
                   <ogc:Literal>NUMCOLORBANDS</ogc:Literal>
                   <ogc:Literal>254</ogc:Literal>
                 </ogc:Function>    
               </ogc:Function>   
             </ogc:Function>
           </ogc:Function>        
         </sld:Transformation>
         <sld:Rule>
           <sld:RasterSymbolizer/>
         </sld:Rule>      
       </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
     </sld:UserStyle>
   </sld:NamedLayer>
 </sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

2) contours:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
   <sld:NamedLayer>
     <sld:Name/>
     <sld:UserStyle>
       <sld:Name/>
       <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
         <sld:Transformation>


            <ogc:Function name="ras:Contour">
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                <ogc:Literal>levels</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>2.0</ogc:Literal>
                <ogc:Literal>3.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>

         </sld:Transformation>
         <Rule>
            <Name>rule1</Name>
            <Title>Contour Line</Title>
            <LineSymbolizer>
              <Stroke>
                <CssParameter name="stroke">#FF0000</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
              </Stroke>
            </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

       </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
     </sld:UserStyle>
   </sld:NamedLayer>
 </sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I've been trying to concatenate :

```
<ogc:Function name="ras:DynamicColorMap">
...
</ogc:Function>
<ogc:Function name="ras:Contour">
...
</ogc:Function>
```

but clearly is not the right approach. Is it possible to combine these two styles or I have to create two separete ones? Or is there a function that I can add to ras:DynamicColorMap to highlight the borders of some areas?

Answer (score 1):

They have to be in different `FeatureTypeStyles` because they produce different types of output (raster and lines) so the symbolizers would get confused if you combine them. But the following should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
   <sld:NamedLayer>
     <sld:Name/>
     <sld:UserStyle>
       <sld:Name/>
       <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
         <sld:Transformation>                       
           <ogc:Function name="ras:DynamicColorMap">
             <ogc:Function name="parameter">
.....
           </ogc:Function>        
         </sld:Transformation>
         <sld:Rule>
           <sld:RasterSymbolizer/>
         </sld:Rule>      
       </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
       <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
         <sld:Transformation>
            <ogc:Function name="ras:Contour">
              <ogc:Function name="parameter">
.....
       </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
     </sld:UserStyle>
   </sld:NamedLayer>
 </sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Awesome! indeed the fact of defining two sld:FeatureTypeStyle makes perfect sense! Thanks